# SwiftUI Child View's content not resizing unless putting the content directly in the main view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, resize

I created a child view in SwiftUI:

```swift
struct MockView : View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            print("ok")
        } label: {
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.red)
                Text("Hello")
                    .frame(width: getFrame().width, height: getFrame().height)
                    .background(Color.gray)
                    .cornerRadius(20)
            }
           
        }

    }
}

func getFrame() -> (width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
        func getWidth() -> CGFloat{
          return UIScreen.main.bounds.width
      }
        func getHeight() -> CGFloat{
          return UIScreen.main.bounds.height
      }
        let height: CGFloat =   getWidth() < getHeight() ? 5 : 10
        let width: CGFloat  =  getWidth() < getHeight() ? 3 : 8
       
        return ( width, height)
    }
```

It is necessary that I Set the Text frame for the text because I need the text to have a specific frame. The function I use to calculate the width and height returns an height and a width for the landscape mode and another height and width for the portrait mode.
The problem is that if I call the MockView from the main view, if I change my devices' orientation, only the rectangle is resized in my mockView, not the text.

```swift
struct MainView: View {
    ...
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in

            ...
            MockView()
            ...
        }
    }
    
}
```

If I put the code of MockView directly into the MainView, I get no resizing errors. The content perfectly resizes and works perfectly.

How come does this happen? How can I make the child view work as well?
I see that removing the frame works but I **need** the text to have that specific frame.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic. What's `getFrame()`? What's `MyDimension`?

Comment: "If I put the code of MockView directly into the MainView, I get no resizing errors" Well then just do that then? Why do you think you need a geometry reader? Also, you should show a [mcve] - something that I can copy-paste into Xcode and reproduce your behaviour.

Comment: Well because my mockView needs to be called multiple times and I can't just go pasting the same code over and over again, I need something clean and portable. The geometry reader is not relevant to the problem. I put it there to let you know I use it in case it might be relevant to the solution to the problem.
I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your child view *dependent on* the size of it's container view. In your example, the child view's body is only computed once, when the associated underlying real view will be created.

You can do something like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            let size = geometry.size
            let screenSize = "(\(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width), \(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)"
            
            // your child view:
            VStack {
                Text("width: \(size.width)")
                Text("height: \(size.height)")
                Text("Screen: \(screenSize)")
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

The child view's container size is *not* the screen size, though. You need your child view account for that. You may however also retrieve the size of the screen as you did already and then also use this to compute your child view.

**Caveat**

If your child view's container size does not change, and this is the only dependency of your child view, the body of your child view will not be computed.

**Using Size Classes**

Another way to maybe solve your problem is leveraging the SwiftUI environment variables `verticalSizeClass` and `horizontalSizeClass` .

```
struct ChildView: View {
    @Environment(\.verticalSizeClass) var verticalSizeClass: UserInterfaceSizeClass?
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var horizontalSizeClass: UserInterfaceSizeClass?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        switch (verticalSizeClass, horizontalSizeClass) {
        case (.regular, .regular):
            ...
        case (.regular, .compact):
            ...

            
        }
    }
}
```

I would suggest to read the documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/verticalsizeclass
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/horizontalsizeclass

If this is still not enough, you may need to resort back to UIKit and catch notification changes for orientation mode. You may do this in a "Model" and forward these notifications to your SwiftUI views.

**Note:**
The general recommendation to do layout is to use Size Classes and the size of the container view – not device orientation.

Comment: ohh thank you, that was so easy, I just ended up adding a fictitious size check in the parent view (getWidth() < getHeight()) that presents the same view either if it is true or false and that worked so smoothly. Now it refreshes perfectly. Thank you for the heads up and the thorough explanation.